# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR returns Load balancer IP how to get the real IP

Tags: iis

Our sites use a load balancer. The server variable "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" returns the load balancer ip address, Is it possible to bypass the load balancer  and get the actual user IP